# Issue accessing kubernetes apis from a pod in azure environment

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm running kubernetes cluster in azure environment and I want to access kubernetes service apis from inside a pod container. But I cannot connect to https://kubernetes/ from inside a pod.

```
kubectl get services
NAME               CLUSTER_IP      EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)
kubernetes         10.16.0.1       <none>        443/TCP
```

Even trying

```
curl -v --cacert /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt https://10.16.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

results in

> - Trying 10.16.0.1...
> - Connected to 10.16.0.1 (10.16.0.1) port 443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 10.16.0.1:443
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 10.16.0.1:443

Comment: Does it work if you run `curl -k ...` (e.g. is it just the SSL verification that is failing)?

Comment: Already tried with -k option. same issue.

Comment: Debugged this issue further. In gce environment from within a pod I can run `curl -v -k https://kubernetes` but in azure environment kubernetes is not getting resolved to corresponding IP address.

Comment: Can you check to see if the kubernetes service has any endpoints registered (run `kubectl get endpoints`)?

Comment: Yes endpoint is assigned but port is 6443

Comment: Can you connect to `https://10.16.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods`?

Comment: Same output as mentioned in the question. curl error code 35. I'm also looking at this conversation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842844/kubernetes-unable-to-access-the-kube-apiserver-from-inside-pod-on-node

If it is **bind-address** option then what does this line mean https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.2.0/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/cloud_config_templates/kubernetes-cluster-main-nodes-template.yml#L218 ?

Comment: Even trying --bind-address=0.0.0.0 `https://10.16.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods` and `https://10.16.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following fix worked:

1. Changed line https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.2.0/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/cloud_config_templates/kubernetes-cluster-main-nodes-template.yml#L218 to have --bind-address=0.0.0.0 option also.
2. Created kubernetes cluster
3. Made kubernetes api port accessible from outside.

You can access kubernetes api using host as node's ip address and the port.